# Can anyone help diagnose what could be causing this (Error: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line) When I start my node app?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, security, pem

I am trying to deploy my site using nginx with a node/express App.

I really can't figure out what this is coming from as the only other google hit is for an auth0 issue which I am not using here.

For reference here's my index.ts file, I'd be happy to provide more code if needed.

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import "dotenv/config";
import {createConnection} from "typeorm";
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-express';
import * as express from "express";
import {typeDefs} from './typeDefs';
import {resolvers} from './resolvers';
import * as session from "express-session";

const startServer = async () => {
  const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    context: ({req}: any)=>({req})
});

await createConnection();

const app = express();

app.use(session({
    secret: "thissupersecretpassword",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));
server.applyMiddleware({ app, cors:{
  credentials: true,
  origin: "http://localhost:3000"
} });



app.listen({ port: 4000 }, () =>
  console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:4000${server.graphqlPath}`)
)
}
startServer();
```